# button inside position fixed table structure cannot click after scrolling on android mobile

Tags: css, html, reactjs, css-position, android-browser

I have a `position: fixed; bottom: 0` table and have a button inside it.

It looks and works fine on a normal browser and ios browser.

However, if we try that table on Android Chrome browser, the button can be click when the url bar is shown, but after you scroll down a bit and make the url bar disappear. The button is no longer clickable anymore.

Here are my HTML structure and css :

```css
.Wrapper {
  z-index: 10;
  height: 72px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed; 
  top: inherit;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
 <Wrapper>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Some text here</td>
          <td><button type="button" onClick={this.clickFunction}>Click Me!</button></td>
        </tr>  
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </Wrapper>
```

Comment: It's hard to reproduce the issue, but it might be related to your `onCLick`. Try changing it to `onclick` instead and also you spelled clikcFunction wrong, or might be that is.

Comment: I try both onClick and onclick but it have the same error